# DialogFlow fulfillment response doesn't appear in default response

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es

I have created a firebase function like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.hello = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send({
    text: "Hi from firebase",
    speech: "Hello from Firebase!"
  });
});
```

As you can see this simply sends a response to the DialogFlow query. I have enabled webhook in DialogFlow for the intent which is sending this query.

I'm following this youtube tutorial [Hack Anons Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArSvSuRINXs&list=PLhPDb5zFmGR3qxa8JfmUdAfVH9Ou41MUx&index=10). Here the response is getting displayed in the Default response field when a user inputs a query. But for me, the response is not displayed in the Default response. For me it shows `NOT Available`. One change between the tutorial in the link and my setup is the API. The tutorial is using V1 API but for me, the API is not available as an option as google mentions that the V1 API is getting disabled from October 23, 2019. I'm using the V2 API. I assume that this is not causing the problem. So why am I not getting the response in the Default response field? Thank you.

Comment: As you're using Node.js, you should use the `dialogflow-fulfillment` library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-fulfillment